# How can I check how much an element was scrolled using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Google Reader and Gmail have scrollable divs that has a shadow on top if the div was scrolled. The shadow changes opacity depending on how much the div was scrolled. How can I check how much an element was scrolled using Javascript/jQuery?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/ and http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/ or http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Comment: @nathanjosiah Add that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft

http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop

or

http://api.jquery.com/scroll

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(el).scrollTop()` to find how many pixels from the top an element (including, say, `body`) has been scrolled.

As @nathanjosiah suggests, check [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) for details.